# How to create fade-in and out navbar with Tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a navbar that looks / acts like the navbar on [anomaly.com](https://www.anomaly.com/home). I really like this effect and am wondering how to create this.

I understand Stack Overflow is not a place to let other write code for you, but I am looking for a step in the right direction. Like how does one go about this and what technologies might be required for something like this?

I tried searching the internet but could not really find what I am looking for, maybe because it didn't quite describe it right. Hence I am here.

Comment: Here's a tip: Check DevTools.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you a bit about the burger menu that you want to use:

```
   <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
  <button class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600" aria-label="Toggle menu" onclick="toggleMenu()">
    <svg class="h-6 w-6 fill-current" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path class="hidden" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4 6h16v2H4V6zm0 5h16v2H4v-2zm16 5H4v2h16v-2z"/>
      <path class="block" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5.5A1.5 1.5 0 014.5 4h15A1.5 1.5 0 0121 5.5v0a1.5 1.5 0 01-1.5 1.5h-15A1.5 1.5 0 013 5.5v0zm0 5A1.5 1.5 0 014.5 9h15A1.5 1.5 0 0121 10.5v0a1.5 1.5 0 01-1.5 1.5h-15A1.5 1.5 0 013 10.5v0zm0 5A1.5 1.5 0 014.5 14h15A1.5 1.5 0 0121 15.5v0a1.5 1.5 0 01-1.5 1.5h-15A1.5 1.5 0 013 15.5v0z"/>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <div class="hidden md:flex md:items-center md:justify-between md:flex-1 lg:w-0" id="menu">
    <nav class="flex flex-col">
      <a href="#" class="text-gray-600 py-2 px-4 block hover:bg-gray-200">Price</a>
      <a href="#" class="text-gray-600 py-2 px-4 block hover:bg-gray-200">Product</a>
      <a href="#" class="text-gray-600 py-2 px-4 block hover:bg-gray-200">About</a>
      <a href="#" class="text-gray-600 py-2 px-4 block hover:bg-gray-200">Home</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```